# Are sqlite triggers guaranteed to always be executed with their corresponding transaction?

Tags: sqlite

If I have the table "my_table" and a trigger for updates or inserts on "my_table" that inserts records into "another_table", what happens if the program crashes between the changes to "my_table" and the trigger operations? Is the whole transaction atomic, in the sense that a failure at any point will abort both the trigger and update?

An example of the statements:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger AFTER INSERT ON my_table
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM another_table WHERE id = NEW.id;
    INSERT INTO another_table VALUES(
        NEW.id,
        IF(NEW.a is NULL, OLD.a, NEW.a)
    );
    INSERT INTO another_table VALUES(
        NEW.id,
        IF(NEW.b is NULL, OLD.b, NEW.b)
    );
END


INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Yes, the whole point of a transaction is to ensure atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

The [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) explains at length how atomic commit works. There is no mention of triggers.

I believe this is because there is nothing special with triggers : transactions handle database changes the same, whether they originate from statements or from triggers.

So if something happens (including operating system crash or power failure) between the statement and the trigger, all the changes will be rolled back.

In fact I think it doesn't really make sense to consider that the trigger happens *after* the statement has completed, specially with 'FOR EACH ROW'.

Comment: My doubt was precisely that the documentation on atomicity makes no mention of triggers, so I was worried that they were effectively subsequent transactions.